# Using NSArray with Monotouch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray, xamarin.ios, mutable

How to insert items into NSArray object in C# (Monotouch)? I don't find appropriate method to do so? In Objective-C side, there is a constructor called "initWithObjects" but I don't find this on C# side.

pom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to answer your question with a question, but are you sure you want to create an NSArray?

I ask because MonoTouch does some work behind the scenes so that you don't have to deal with NSArray.

If you go to [the MonoTouch API Design page](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/API_Design) and do an in-page search for "NSArray", you'll find this:

> Instead of dealing with NSString and NSArray the runtime instead exposes these as C# strings and strongly typed arrays throughout the API.

In other words, unless you have a specific reason to, you don't have to mess with NSArray.

But, if you *do* have a reason, or if it's your preference, then Jason's answer is correct:

```
NSArray someArray = NSArray.FromNSObjects(thingOne, thingTwo, thingThree);
```

The only thing I'd add is that, if you're an Objective-C dev and giving MonoTouch a try, you're used to this:

```
NSArray *someArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1, obj2, obj3, nil];
```

The difference is the "nil" at the end of the Objective-C version. MonoTouch's NSArray doesn't have this same requirement. You just pass it the objects you want it to contain, and it happily does so. No terminating null required :)

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank for bringing the internal efforts of MonoTouch to my attention. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not using Monotouch - but if you're looking to manipulate an NSArray, you're going to want to use it's cousin, NSMutableArray.

Comment: This also applies to NSDictionary, as there is NSMutableDictionary as well. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this static method is what you want:

```
public static NSArray FromNSObjects (params NSObject[] items);
```

Used like this:

```
NSArray arr = NSArray.FromNSObjects(obj1, obj2, obj3);
```

Comment: That isn't inserting, that's creating WITH objects.

Comment: This was actually what I wanted, I just had formulated my question wrong.

Comment: Sneakyness: Based on his question, it sounded like he wanted the MonoTouch way to call `initWithObjects`. Pompair: you could mark mine as accepted :)